# Getting an extra entry in array for each newline

Tags: c#, arrays, string, trim

For the following code...

```
IEnumerable<string> items=searchterms.Trim().Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
foreach (var item in items) {
```

I'm getting an item of length 0 in-between each searchterm item. I've used similar code elsewhere and not run into this, so not sure why it's happenning now. What do I need to add here to get rid of these extra entries? i.e. so that the number of items matches the number of terms in the input. I have a work-around (skip items with length 0), but it's an annoyance that the numbers don't match, and I would like to fix it for displaying progress purposes. i.e. item i+1 of items.count.

P.S. this is in Xamarin Forms on UWP.

thanks,
  Donald.

Comment: How about including some input so we can replicate?

Comment: It's just a list of searchterms - in this case barcodes - one per line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the newline is composed from 2 characters (on most systems anyway, \r and \n), you may be getting an extra empty string as the string between these characters.

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<string> items=searchterms.Trim().Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (var item in items) {
```

Comment: That works. Thank you! I thought it might have something to do with the \r, but I also thought the whole point of using Environment.NewLine was that it knows what the relevant characters are for newline on that platform, in this case \r\n?

Comment: That's still true. The code still uses Environment.NewLine. The point is we want to treat it as one string and not turn it into a char array.

Comment: Ah, ok. I don't remember why I used char array in the first place, other than it solved an issue I was having with the code in VS at the time (to do with types from memory).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you split by a char array of `{ '\r', '\n' }` which means either symbol is regarded as a separator, not the whole sequence of `"\r\n"`, i.e. there is an empty string in `"\r\n"` in between.

To split by the whole sequence only use a string array of one element

```
IEnumerable<string> items = searchterms.Trim().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine, }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

This will not produce an empty item unless there are to consecutive `"\r\n"` in the string. If you also want to remove empty items in such case you can use the `RemoveEmptyEntries` string split option.

```
IEnumerable<string> items = searchterms.Trim().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine, }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: You were just beaten to the punch on this one, but thanks for providing the extra info!